# Create dictionary and append certain fields and columns to existing dataframe (based on condition in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an existing dataframe, df, where I would like to append several columns and values to ***if*** values in the existing columns meet a certain criteria

**Data**

```
location    type    count   year
ny          marvel  1       2021
ca          dc      1       2021
```

**Desired**

```
location    type    count   year    strength    points  cost
ny          marvel  1       2021    13          1000    100,000
ca          dc      1       2021    10          500     200,000
```

IF the string in the type column is  'marvel' then strength = 13, points = 1000 and cost = 100,000
IF the string in the type column is   'dc'    then strength = 10, points = 500  and cost = 200,000
essentially, I would like to create 3 new columns and add values in these columns based on certain criteria

```
         strength   points  cost    
 marvel  13         1000    100,000 
 dc      10         500     200,000
```

**Doing**

```
  #empty dictionary
  marvel = {}
  dc = {}

  
  marvel_a = {strength:13,  points: 1000, cost: 100,000}
  dc_a     = {strength:10,  points: 500,  cost: 200,000}


  df.assign({'strength': '', 'points': '', 'cost': ''})
```

I am creating a dictionary that will hold the key and the value and then I am thinking that I need to append this to the existing dataframe, however, the dictionary is working fine, but I am not able to add these 3 new columns.

Any suggestion or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dataframe `df`:

```
  location    type  count  year
0       ny  marvel      1  2021
1       ca      dc      1  2021
```

And dataframe `df_criteria`:

```
        strength  points     cost
marvel        13    1000  100,000
dc            10     500  200,000
```

*Note the index of this dataframe.*

Then:

```py
print(df.merge(df_criteria, how="left", left_on="type", right_index=True))
```

Prints:

```
  location    type  count  year  strength  points     cost
0       ny  marvel      1  2021        13    1000  100,000
1       ca      dc      1  2021        10     500  200,000
```

Comment: Ah I see, so create a new table which holds the criteria and then concatenate them. This is clever thank you I will try

Answer (score 1):

assume that your DataFrame is df

```
import numpy as np

df['strength'] = np.where(df['type']=='marvel', 13, 
                    np.where(df['type']=='dc', 10, None))

df['points'] = np.where(df['type']=='marvel', 1000, 
                    np.where(df['type']=='dc', 500, None))

df['cost'] = np.where(df['type']=='marvel', 100000, 
                    np.where(df['type']=='dc', 200000, None))
```

let me explain

numpy where function is np.where(condition, value if condition is True, value if condition is False)

I use overlapped np.where because there are two conditios, marvel and dc.

Comment: Thank you I will try this solution as well

Answer (score 1):

Also an alternative where you have dict of each attribute:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['ny', 'ca'], 'type': ['marvel','dc'], 'count':[1, 1], 'year': [2021, 2021]})

strength = {'marvel': 13, 'dc': 10}
points = {'marvel': 1000, 'dc': 500}
cost = {'marvel': 100000, 'dc': 200000}

df['strength'] = df['type'].map(strength)
df['points'] = df['type'].map(points)
df['cost'] = df['type'].map(cost)
```